# How to add two related forms in a notes view?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Ok,I have a situation where I need to display a view that contains field value from two forms which is connected via a "CVNo" field. At first I thought it was simple and dived in. I added the form names in the view selection formula of the notes view and then created columns and assigned their respective values, but what happened was the output I got from doing so is a very jumbled and cluttered view. Based on my understanding the notes view displayed the column values from each form differently. I don't know how to do this or if this possible in notes view. All help and suggestions and are very appreciated.

Comment: You want to display "field1" if  the form of the document is "form1" and "field2" if the form is "form2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lotus Notes view you cannot display documents connected to each other by a custom field. The only connection which can be displayed in Lotus Notes view is parent->response document hierarchy.

And please note that you do not create view that displays values from forms. You create view to display field values from documents, which are filtered to be shown in this view.

If you have documents, with field `Form`, one `Form1` and another `Form2`, then create a view with selection formula:

```
SELECT Form = "Form1" | Form = "Form2"
```

Every row in the view represents a document (either with `Form1` or `Form2` value in the `Form` field).

And every column may contain a field name or @-formula to evaluate with every shown document to display a value in this column.

Comment: Thanks for that response Rafael. I'm still new in Notes dev environment so sometimes I thought things that are usable in relational databases. Thank you.

Comment: Lotus Notes is not a relational db. It is document oriented database. And documents cannot be connected to each other like in relational databases. They can be connected by ids (universal ids), but this connection either related to parent-response hierarchy, or related to connections handled only by lotusscript/@-formula code in buttons/agent. But not in view selection formulas. View selection formulas look like SQL language, but view in Lotus Notes is a different thing than a view in a relational database.

Comment: and check this link: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/sg246854.html?OpenDocument There is a dev. guide for beginners. Don't worry about version (6). The main principles are the same, regardless of version. Also take a look at Lotus Designer help. Launch Lotus Designer, and select from menu Help - Help Contents. Good luck.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of help. Thank you very much!